# create visual force page without creating apex class for look up field

Tags: visualforce, javascript

Hi I am trying to show look up fields on opportunities and accounts in same visualforce page, then submit it through API, the submission through API call has been done I just wanna know if I can get the look up fields, so the user can pick the right parent account or account owner, or opportunity owner and pass the value via javascript to my rest API call , this doesnt work `<apex:inputField value={“!Account.name”} />`

```
  <apex:page showHeader="true" standardController="account" sidebar="false" standardStylesheets="false" docType="html-5.0" >



    <div class="container">
<label for="name">Account Name</label>
      <input type="text" name="Name" id="name" />
      <br></br>
      <button id="button">Submit</button>
      <div id="status"></div>
    </div> <td class="labelCol">
          <apex:inputField value={“!account.name”} />
                        </td>
                        <td class="data2Col">
                        <input id="j_id0:j_id3:sessionId" type="text" name="sessionId" class="PrequalStreet" style="width:246px;"
                                value="{!getSessionID()}" />
                        </td>

    </body>


    <script>
    $('#button').click(function(){
var parent = $( "input[id*='parent']" ).val();
console.log('parent is' + parent);
```

Comment: The account name field is just that, the name.  You need to reference the parent account relationship instead.

Comment: @MattLacey  how do i do that in visualforce page?

Comment: @Metawaa: You can refer the desired fields using lookup relationship fields that you have on Account Object. Also, do you also want to show Opportunity lookups on this same page? or only account lookups?

Comment: @user36778 I wanna show both of them in the same page , using only visualforce page. Not any apex class. I am doing the whole submission via sobject tree post API rest

Answer (score 0):

You need to use an actual lookup field as the value for `apex:inputField` to get the lookup functionality.  Example:  if you want to lookup Account, then you need something like

```
<apex:inputField value="{!Contact.AccountId}" />
```

One way to accomplish this is to set up a dummy object in your controller to be used specifically for your lookups:

```
public Contact dummyCon { get; set; }
```

And in your VF page:

```
<apex:inputField value="{!dummyCon.AccountId"} />
```

Doing a lookup for Opportunity is trickier because I'm not too familiar with standard objects related to opp.  Maybe the Quote object?  You'll have to experiment.

Comment: I didnt wanna use a controller. that was the only concern. I thought visual force page on its own using standard object would do it